# Is there a difference between Phongap config.xml and Cordova config.xml?

Tags: android, cordova, config

As I'm working on my Phonegap app, I've noticed some differences between the config for [Adobe online build](https://build.phonegap.com/) and cordova config (local).

Cordova: `<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false"/>`
Adobe Phonegap: `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />`

1. Phonegap uses dashes and Cordova does not. Do they mix? Can I use dashes for local builds and non dashes for the online Adobe build?
2. And can I use Cordova settings as long as I add `android-` prefix like `phonegap-version`?

I also see:

Cordova:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" />
<platform>
```

Phonegap:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/icon-60@3x.png" />
```

3. Do they also mix? Or does it mean I have to have one config file for local build and another for online builds?

Comment: What does the PhoneGap Build site say to do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap config.xml uses a dtd wich extends the dtd of cordova's config.xml to allow use of some specific tags like the gap:.

You can use the phonegap dtd with cordova with no issue. If you use the cordova dtd with phonegap build, some options may be ignored.

Phonegap build need some secific tags to handle things that are done using the CLI when you build locally, like the plugins wich are installed using `<gap:plugin>`